# Asp.net mvc file download is not working while using Rotativa

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I'm new to using Rotativa. I'm hitting my Rotativa function as:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "InwardReceiption", FormMethod.Post)) {
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return new ActionAsPdf("ViewDetails");
}

public ActionResult ViewDetails()
{
    return view();
}
```

Here I'm hitting the function `ViewDetails` and I get this error:

> Failed loading page localhost:49788/InwardReceiption/ViewDetails

Sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with `--load-error-handling ignore`

But then I get this error:

> Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please add the error you got.

Comment: its saying your hitting your function n times

Comment: Could you please copy and paste the exactly text of the error? And this error occurs when you call the `ViewDetails` or `Test` method?

Comment: Error: Failed loading page http://localhost:49788/InwardReceiption/ViewDetails (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.

Comment: This is My Error

Comment: Do you have a view called ViewDetails.cshtml in your project?

Comment: Your code shows a lower-case method name in `return view();` in the `ViewDetails()` action -- this should be `return View();` -- can you try this please?